# Retain previous searches on form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have been tasked with building a search form in rails, which outputs searches continously on the screen following form submit, until the browser is closed. For example.

List of Searches
10am - Searched for "car" returned "ford"
11am - Searched for "train" returned "virgin trains"

Obviously, the issue is, that as soon as I submit the form the page reloads and the previous search is lost. I am wondering what the best way to save the results of previous searches to be displayed in the view?

I did initally think of saving the results into some form of session variable, but it didnt seem to work properly. Heres what I would have liked...

```
SearchController
session["searches"] = []

def index
 if params[:search]
   latest_search = Search.new(search_term,time_of_search,search_results)
   session["searches"].push(latest_search) 
 end
 @searches = session["searches"]     
end
```

Then I could loop through the @searches in the index view. However, this didnt seem to work, and didnt seem a good solution.

Obvioulsy ajax is an option, but I havent used ajax with rails as yet so am looking for a simpler solution for now. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume the searches you are displaying are for that users session only and not for the whole site?

Comment: Its for the whole site for now, as I havent implemented user sessions.

Comment: Well the easiest answers in my mind are to either store all searches in a db and pull them out. Or do something purely front end like pubnub

Comment: Yeah, the issue with saving into the db is that previous searches need to be cleared on page refresh, so the session seems to be the most obvious choice there. Will have a look at pubnub, but was looking for a solution without having to learn another technology.